# GFCIs tripping on their own

Tags: electrical

I have GFCIs on their own breakers that will trip when lights on a separate breaker are turned on. To reiterate, the lights that trip the GFCIs are not fed from the tripping GFCIs. What could cause that?

Comment: bad wiring and a cross connection from one of the leads of the GFCI

Answer (score 5):

Shared neutrals could cause this.  If the two circuits are both in a box together somewhere, and the neutrals from the two circuits are tied together, this could cause this problem.

It's common practice for DIYers (and some "professionals") to simply connect all the neutrals in a box together. If there are two circuits present in the box, simply connecting all the neutrals together is not proper. In the past, this normally didn't cause any noticeable problems. However, now that GFCI and AFCI protection is common, this bad wiring practice becomes more apparent.

Comment: What would be the correct way to connect the neutrals. I am also guilty so doing the same thing.